# Unable to resolve "idb" from "node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\esm\index.esm2017.js" in expo/react-native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

// imports of screens and react standards dependency

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation"
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack"
import LoadingScreen from "./screens/LoadingScreen"
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen"
import RegisterScreen from "./screens/RegisterScreen"
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen"
```

*//firebase import*

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/messaging';
import 'firebase/analytics';
```

//firebase config

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "privateforquestion",
  authDomain: "privateforquestion",
  projectId: "privateforquestion",
  storageBucket: "privateforquestion",
  messagingSenderId: "privateforquestion",
  appId: "privateforquestion"
};
```

// Initialize Firebase

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//creating navigations and auth

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
});

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Register: RegisterScreen,
});

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Loading: LoadingScreen,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Loading",
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading your firebase to 9.2.0.

I had the same issue using expo 46.0.9 and react-native 0.69.5, I have downgraded firebase to 9.2.0, which works for the time being.

> npm install firebase@9.2.0

**Update**

Create a file named **metro.config.js** on the root of the project.

and add the below code in the file.

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
defaultConfig.resolver.sourceExts.push('cjs');
module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

This should work with the latest version on firebase > 9.10.0